# How to look up the Census Block Code of an address?

Tags: us-census, census, address, excel

I am trying to divide up a pool of addresses currently in Microsoft Excel according to the Census Block Code. Would anyone tell me where can I access data like that? Any instructions? Moreover, is it possible to retrieve those data with VBA or any programming API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The U.S. Census Bureau has a [geocoder API service](https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/) that you might want to look into. Here is the [landing page](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/technical-documentation/complete-technical-documentation/census-geocoder.html) with some additional information.

I was able to return information on the Census Block of a given address using the ["FIND GEOGRAPHIES USING..." OPTION --> One Line](https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/onelineaddress?form) option.